# Networking Issue - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox-networking

I have an Ubuntu Server (18.04 LTS) VPS setup on a HYPER-V host system..

The Ubuntu network interface is configured as follows:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses: [192.168.1.74/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
         addresses:
            - "8.8.8.8"
            - "8.8.4.4"
```

The Host Machine (Hyper-V) is on `192.168.1.73`

The VPS is able to communicate fine with the outside world, but it cannot access any services on the Host machine from the VPS, even just pinging `192.168.1.73` fails.

Would really appreciate any advice on what could be wrong here.

Thanks,

**EDIT 1 :**
Just to add... the host machine is a Windows 2012 R2 instance, there are port blocking rules configured in Windows routing and remote access, but the services I am trying to reach have both inbound and outbound rules to allow traffic from any location, and are reachable from other locations - just not from the VPS. Also, ufw is inactive on the VPS.